# SQL -- select a random row in O(1) time?

Tags: sql

A curiosity question -- whenever I've seen a random row selected via SQL, I've seen it like this:

`SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;`

Which works well, but is `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the table. (This isn't a real performance problem I have, the DB is plenty fast, it's an academic question).

Is there a way to implement an `O(1)` random select in any flavor of SQL, like I could in other languages? (e.g. generate a random number `r` between 1 and n, and choose the `r`th row).

Comment: What evidence leads you to believe that the query you posted runs in `O(n)` (where `n == rowcount`) time?

Comment: Algorithm R https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling could pick a random tuple in O(N) operations. But it is not implemented in any DBMS. Given known N, and the presence of an ordinal column would reduce  to O(log(N)) in case of a btree index, or O(1) given a hash index,

Comment: @Dai: Thanks for asking, I should have said! `EXPLAIN` mentions that it will do a "sort with a random key", which I took literally and seems to rule out the sort of optimizations you mention, but perhaps there is a way. Is the output of `EXPLAIN` a good guide to performance, in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is predicated on the assumption that database queries are somehow `O(n)` - they aren't (otherwise `JOIN`s would be horrendously expensive).

SQL is an abstraction of the table/row-stores present in RDBMs systems based on relational algebra, it makes no reference or claims w.r.t. runtime complexity, which is good, because it means that the implementing database system can make use of indexes, in-memory stores, special-case handlers and other optimizations to deliver the correct results with varying runtime performance. This also means that SQL does not expose implementation details, such as physical row-numbers, block addresses, B-tree nodes, etc. When you write a query you should not concern yourself with those things, what matters is the algebraic-correctness of your query.

So a particularly smart DBMS could have a special-case handler for `ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1` which would run in `O(1)` time.

...however it seems that MySQL does not optimize for this case, so a better approach is needed.

Try this:

```
SELECT @n := COUNT(*) FROM table_name
SET @offset := ROUND( RAND() * @n )
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY clustered_indexed_column LIMIT 1 OFFSET @offset
```

Where `clustered_indexex_column` is a column that could be your primary-key or otherwise a column that is very cheap to perform an `ORDER BY` on. Assuming the indexes are set-up correctly, this query should run in the order of `O( log(n) )` or better.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort is O(n*log(n))
2. Create a table with seqential number column including hash index on that column, and like you suggested, generate a random number and select the relevant row.

http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/oracle-11g-hash-indexes-mc02/#.WBE0hBmEbqA

Answer (score 0):

O(n) doesn't necessarily mean fast.  The following should do what you want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM table_name t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table_name) x
      WHERE RANDOM() <= 100.0 / cnt
     ) t
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1;
```

With no indexes, this is processed as:

- Calculating `cnt` is a full table scan, which is O(n).
- Processing the `where` clause for filtering produces approximately 100 rows, independent of the size of the overall table.
- Doing the `ORDER BY` is "constant" for large values of n (admittedly, if n is 100 or less, then this "constant" is more like O(n log(n))

This does depend on the fact that a very unlucky streak of random numbers will not find even one match.  I think that is so unlikely that the possibility can be excluded.